# Drop rows which match certain values in R correctly

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to remove records\rows that match a certain value in R.

This is what I have now:

```
RawSurvey <- read.csv("/Survey/RawSurvey.csv")

Country = RawSurvey[,132] #132nd variable is Country

Survey <- RawSurvey[which(Country != 'Israel' 
                      & Country != 'Canada'
                      & Country != 'Ukraine'
                      & Country != 'Afghanistan'
                      & Country != 'Oman'
                      & Country != 'Argentina'
                      ),]
```

I don't think it is dropping the records - I mean when I do summary(Survey$Country) they still show up but with 0 i.e. Argentina - 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save a lot of complexity by using `%in%`, like

```
countriesToDrop<-c("Israel","Canada","Ukraine","Afghanistan","Oman","Argentina");
Survey<-RawSurvey[!(RawSurvey[,132]%in%countriesToDrop),]
```

The fact that dropped countries are showing up with counts 0 is a normal, expected behaviour of factor vectors; if you wish, you can drop them by recalculating factor levels, like this:

```
Survey[,132]<-factor(Survey[,132])
```